# Create JSON-Schema for JSON-File containing a various number of addresses

Tags: c#, json

I got a JSON-File, that contains a various number of addresses.
Now I need a JSON-Schema to validate the complete JSON-File:

My JSON-File is looking similar to this:

```
[
   {
       "ID": "FIRST",
       "Name" : "FirstName",
       "ZIP" : "0815"
   },
   {
       "ID": "SECOND",
       "Name" : "SecondName",
       "ZIP" : "4711"
   },
   {
       "ID": "THIRD",
       "Name" : "ThirdName",
       "ZIP" : "123"
   }
]
```

These are only three addresses, but the JSON-File can contain much more of them.
How has the Schema to look like?

**I want to use the Schema-Generator to create the JSON-Schema!!!**

Thanx for your help in advance.

Comment: It look like a simple schema with no a lot of validation. Type an array of address item with 3 properties ID/Name/Zip all string, not mandatory. Not a lot to do using the specification https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/index.html. You commented that you want to use a generator, so you can, simply copy past in any generatorn, and work from there.

Comment: https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/GenerateSchema.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [newtonsoft Json.net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema).
You can generate the Schema from an object. [doc](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/GenerateSchema.htm)

Your address class is simply :

```
public class Address
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ZIP { get; set; }
}
```

The convertion will be :

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Schema;


JsonSchemaGenerator generator = new JsonSchemaGenerator();
JsonSchema schema = generator.Generate(typeof(Address[]));
```

[Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WxivBl)

Comment: Hi Drag and Drop.

I did nearly the same like you, but I forgot the []-Brackets in ...typeof(Address[])

Thanx a lot for the fast answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NJsonSchema](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NJsonSchema) Library (accessible via Nuget Packages) for generating schema from Json directly. For example,

```
 var schema = JsonSchema.FromSampleJson(json);
 var result = schema.ToJson();
```

Sample Output

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "$ref": "#/definitions/Anonymous"
  },
  "definitions": {
    "Anonymous": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "ID": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "Name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "ZIP": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```